# Angular - what Lifecycle event to use if i want a certain action to happen when two buttons are pressed or when one of the buttons changes?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, function, button

Lets say i have 6 buttons. 3 on top and 3 on bottom :

```js
let valuesum;
let value1;
let value2;

let ButtonGroup1clicked= false;
let buttonGroup2Clicked= false;

function click1 (value){
value1= value;
console.log(value1);
ButtonGroup1clicked= true;
console.log(ButtonGroup1clicked);
};

function click2 (value){
value2= value;
console.log(value2);
buttonGroup2Clicked= true;
console.log(buttonGroup2Clicked);
};

function sumvalue(vaaalue1,vaaalue2){
console.log("SUM: ",vaaalue1+vaaalue2);
};


if(ButtonGroup1clicked===true && ButtonGroup2clicked===true){
 console.log(value1,value2);
sumvalue(value1, value2);
};


function runThis(){

if(ButtonGroup1clicked===true && buttonGroup2Clicked===true){
 console.log(value1,value2);
sumvalue(value1, value2);
};

};
```

```html
<div>
    <button onclick = "click1(1),runThis()">1</button>
    <button onclick = "click1(2),runThis()">2</button>
    <button onclick = "click1(3),runThis()">3</button>
    </div>


    <div>
    <button onclick = "click2(4),runThis()">4</button>
    <button onclick = "click2(5),runThis()">5</button>
    <button onclick = "click2(6),runThis()">6</button>
    </div>
```

I want to add this function if one button on the top and one botton of the bottom are pressed, and after both pressed, if i press another button, lets say on the top, the function executes again.

I know how to do it notmal way, but i dont know how to implement that on angular with classes. And what  Lifecycle event to use. (ngOnChanges()..etc etc)

Answer (score 0):

The lifecycle hooks have nothing to do here. You only need to translate vanilla JS to Typescript. And that implies do everything in the context of a class. And replace `onclick` event binding with `(click)` event.

Controller

```js
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  valuesum: any;
  value1: any;
  value2: any;

  ButtonGroup1clicked = false;
  buttonGroup2Clicked = false;

  public click1 (value){
    this.value1= value;
    console.log(this.value1);
    this.ButtonGroup1clicked= true;
    console.log(this.ButtonGroup1clicked);
  }

  public click2 (value){
    this.value2= value;
    console.log(this.value2);
    this.buttonGroup2Clicked= true;
    console.log(this.buttonGroup2Clicked);
  }

  public sumvalue(vaaalue1,vaaalue2){
    console.log("SUM: ",vaaalue1+vaaalue2);
  }

  public runThis() {
    if(this.ButtonGroup1clicked === true && this.buttonGroup2Clicked === true){
      console.log(this.value1, this.value2);
      this.sumvalue(this.value1, this.value2);
    }
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<div>
  <button (click)="click1(1);runThis()">1</button>
  <button (click)="click1(2);runThis()">2</button>
  <button (click)="click1(3);runThis()">3</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button (click)="click2(4);runThis()">4</button>
  <button (click)="click2(5);runThis()">5</button>
  <button (click)="click2(6);runThis()">6</button>
</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9gkr5s)

If you're new to Angular, I'd recommend to go through the tutorial [here](https://angular.io/tutorial). It introduces some basics.